# Минус перед аргументом

Tags: python

что значит этот фрагмент кода? -(heappop(high)) при том, что high массив отрицательных чисел?

Comment: А что значит минус в этом выражении `-1`? И где тут аргумент чего?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Функция `heappop` возвращает одно число из массива `high`. А минус приводит его к противоположному по знаку значению